# Unity: Disabling OptimizedFramePacing fixes Bluestacks blackscreen but cuases jitter

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluestacks

The Problem: when running a unity build in Bluestacks you get a black screen. The only solution I have found for it is to disable "OptimzedFramePacing" in PayerSettings when building which fixes the blackscreen, but causes another problem, which is: on android your game gets a little jittery.

I use unity 2020.3.33f1. tested on Bluestacks 5.3 and 5.8

I have tried with empty project with only a few rigidbody2d falling and result is the same.

in the last few days i have searched and read all the topics about this, which are very few considering it looks like a big issue!

Things I have tried but failed:

-fixing bluestack black screen by any other ways. (blitType, Custom main manifest, Changing Graphic API)

-changing OptimzedFramePacing only if we run in bluestack, which is impossible because OptimzedFramePacing can not be set at runtime.

I know OptimzedFramePacing=false should result in a little jitter. is there a way to fix bluestacks blackscreen and keep OptimzedFramePacing=true?
or any other solution?

I really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.
Thank you.